# How to delete and add items in jquery mobile listview

Tags: jquery-mobile-listview

I am learning you to use Jquery Mobile, and I have been combining several codes in order to make a list using listview where I can delete and item from the list or modify the position of the selected item into the list.

First of all I use the delete example from the jquery mobile help and add a extra button for testing purposes in the page footer in order to add a dummy item into the list. Up to here it works partially. If I do not click in a previous predefined list delete item, my adding function will do not work. But If I click first in  the delete icon and then click my adding button this works however the new item delete button do not have enabled the delete button click event. Can any of you have an idea or suggestion how I can resolve this. Thanks in adavance and here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Swipe list - jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/_assets/js/jquery.mobile.demos.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {

            // Swipe to remove list item
            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#list li.ui-li", function( event ) {
                var listitem = $( this ),
                    // These are the classnames used for the CSS transition
                    dir = event.type === "swipeleft" ? "left" : "right",
                    // Check if the browser supports the transform (3D) CSS transition
                    transition = $.support.cssTransform3d ? dir : false;

                    confirmAndDelete( listitem, transition );

            });

            // If it's not a touch device...
            if ( ! $.mobile.support.touch ) {

                // Remove the class that is used to hide the delete button on touch devices             
                $( "#list" ).removeClass( "touch" );

                // Click delete split-button to remove list item
                $( ".delete" ).on( "click", function() {
                    var listitem = $( this ).parent( "li.ui-li" );

                    confirmAndDelete( listitem );
                });
            }

            function confirmAndDelete( listitem, transition ) {
                // Highlight the list item that will be removed
                listitem.addClass( "ui-btn-down-d" );
                // Inject topic in confirmation popup after removing any previous injected topics
                $( "#confirm .topic" ).remove();
                listitem.find( ".topic" ).clone().insertAfter( "#question" );
                // Show the confirmation popup
                $( "#confirm" ).popup( "open" );
                // Proceed when the user confirms
                $( "#confirm #yes" ).on( "click", function() {
                    // Remove with a transition
                    if ( transition ) {

                        listitem
                            // Remove the highlight
                            .removeClass( "ui-btn-down-d" )
                            // Add the class for the transition direction
                            .addClass( transition )
                            // When the transition is done...
                            .on( "webkitTransitionEnd transitionend otransitionend", function() {
                                // ...the list item will be removed
                                listitem.remove();
                                // ...the list will be refreshed and the temporary class for border styling removed
                                $( "#list" ).listview( "refresh" ).find( ".ui-li.border" ).removeClass( "border" );
                            })
                            // During the transition the previous list item should get bottom border
                            .prev( "li.ui-li" ).addClass( "border" );

                    }
                    // If it's not a touch device or the CSS transition isn't supported just remove the list item and refresh the list
                    else {

                        listitem.remove();
                        $( "#list" ).listview( "refresh" );

                    }
                });
                // Remove active state and unbind when the cancel button is clicked
                $( "#confirm #cancel" ).on( "click", function() {
                    listitem.removeClass( "ui-btn-down-d" );
                    $( "#confirm #yes" ).off(); 
                });

                $("#btn-agre").click(function(listitem){
            $("#list").append('<li><a href="#demo-mail"><h3>Agregado</h3><p class="topic"><strong>Re: Agregado</strong></p><p>veamos si funciona en la hora y cosa adecuada</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:48</strong>PM</p></a><a href="#" class="delete" data-inline="false">Delete</a></li>');
            $( "#list" ).listview( "refresh" ); 

            });
            }


        });


    </script>
    <style>
        /* Left transition */
        li.ui-li.left {
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease;
            -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
            -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease;
            -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: transform 250ms ease;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            border-top-width: 0; /* We switch to border bottom on previous list item */
            border-right-width: 1px;
        }
        /* Right transition */      
        li.ui-li.right {
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease;
            -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
            -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease;
            -o-transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 250ms ease;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            border-top-width: 0; /* We switch to border bottom on previous list item */
            border-left-width: 1px;
        }
        /* Border bottom for the previous list item during the transition*/
        li.ui-li.border {
            border-bottom-width: 1px;
        }
        /* Hide the delete button on touch devices */
        .touch .delete {
            display: none;
        }
        .touch .ui-link-inherit {
            padding-right: 15px !important;
        }
        /* Custom styling for the popup */
        #confirm {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-color: #044062; /* Fallback for older browsers */
            border-color: rgba(4,64,98,.4);
            background: #456f9a; /* Fallback for older browsers */
            background: rgba(69,111,154,.8);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(69,111,154,.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 6px rgba(255,255,255,.1), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(69,111,154,.3);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(69,111,154,.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 6px rgba(255,255,255,.1), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(69,111,154,.3);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(69,111,154,.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 6px rgba(255,255,255,.1), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(69,111,154,.3);
            max-width: 250px;
        }
        #confirm p {
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
            margin-bottom: .75em;
        }
        /* Make the buttons inherit the popup border-radius (.ui-corner-all) */
        #confirm div, #confirm .ui-btn-corner-all {
            -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
            border-radius: inherit;
        }
        #confirm #cancel {
            background-image: none;
        }
        #confirm .topic.ui-li-desc {
            font-size: inherit; /* The cloned topic will have class ui-li-desc so we negate the font-size settings of this class */
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="demo-page" data-title="Inbox" data-theme="d">
<!--
NOTE: If you modify this page make sure you copy your modifications over to
#sample-page below so that your modifications will be reflected in the source
code view
-->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Inbox</h1>
       </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

        <ul id="list" class="touch" data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Avery Walker</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Re: Dinner Tonight</strong></p>
                    <p>Sure, let's plan on meeting at Highland Kitchen at 8:00 tonight. Can't wait! </p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:48</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete" data-inline="false">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Amazon.com</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>4-for-3 Books for Kids</strong></p>
                    <p>As someone who has purchased children's books from our 4-for-3 Store, you may be interested in these featured books.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:37</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Mike Taylor</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Re: This weekend in Maine</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey little buddy, sorry but I can't make it up to vacationland this weekend. Maybe next weekend?</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>3:24</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Redfin</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Redfin listing updates for today</strong></p>
                    <p>There are 3 updates for the home on your watchlist: 1 updated MLS listing and 2 homes under contract.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>2:52</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Angela Smith</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Link Request</strong></p>
                    <p>My name is Angela Smith, SEO Consultant. I've greatly enjoyed looking through your site and I was wondering if you'd be interested in providing a link</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>1:24</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>11:24</strong>AM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
                    <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">

      <a id="btn-agre" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-icon="gear" >agregar</a>
    </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div id="confirm" class="ui-content" data-role="popup" data-theme="none">
        <a id="cancel"  href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">cerrar</a>

        <p id="question">Are you sure you want to delete</p>
         <a id="btn-arriba" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-u" >subir</a>
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
    <a id="yes"  data-icon="delete" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="d" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back" data-align="right">eliminar</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <a id="btn-bajar" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-d"  >bajar</a>


         </div><!-- /popup -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="sample-page" data-title="Inbox" data-theme="d">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Inbox</h1>
        <a href="#demo-intro" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">Refresh</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

        <ul id="list" class="touch" data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Avery Walker</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Re: Dinner Tonight</strong></p>
                    <p>Sure, let's plan on meeting at Highland Kitchen at 8:00 tonight. Can't wait! </p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:48</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Amazon.com</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>4-for-3 Books for Kids</strong></p>
                    <p>As someone who has purchased children's books from our 4-for-3 Store, you may be interested in these featured books.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:37</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Mike Taylor</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Re: This weekend in Maine</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey little buddy, sorry but I can't make it up to vacationland this weekend. Maybe next weekend?</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>3:24</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Redfin</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Redfin listing updates for today</strong></p>
                    <p>There are 3 updates for the home on your watchlist: 1 updated MLS listing and 2 homes under contract.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>2:52</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Angela Smith</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Link Request</strong></p>
                    <p>My name is Angela Smith, SEO Consultant. I've greatly enjoyed looking through your site and I was wondering if you'd be interested in providing a link</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>1:24</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>11:24</strong>AM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
                    <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Avery Walker</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Re: Dinner Tonight</strong></p>
                    <p>Sure, let's plan on meeting at Highland Kitchen at 8:00 tonight. Can't wait! </p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:48</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Amazon.com</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>4-for-3 Books for Kids</strong></p>
                    <p>As someone who has purchased children's books from our 4-for-3 Store, you may be interested in these featured books.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>4:37</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Mike Taylor</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Re: This weekend in Maine</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey little buddy, sorry but I can't make it up to vacationland this weekend. Maybe next weekend?</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>3:24</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Redfin</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Redfin listing updates for today</strong></p>
                    <p>There are 3 updates for the home on your watchlist: 1 updated MLS listing and 2 homes under contract.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>2:52</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Angela Smith</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Link Request</strong></p>
                    <p>My name is Angela Smith, SEO Consultant. I've greatly enjoyed looking through your site and I was wondering if you'd be interested in providing a link</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>1:24</strong>PM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>11:24</strong>AM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#demo-mail">
                    <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
                    <p class="topic"><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
                    <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div id="confirm" class="ui-content" data-role="popup" data-theme="none">

        <p id="question">Are you sure you want to delete</p>

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a id="yes" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Yes</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a id="cancel" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>                
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /popup -->

</div><!-- /page -->


<div data-role="page" id="demo-mail" data-title="Demo" data-theme="d">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <a href="#demo-page" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

        <p>This is just a landing page for demo purposes.</p>

        <p><a href="#demo-page" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Back</a></p>


    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to a listview it is very simple, just use the .append method on whatever DOM element where the append method would take markup as its parameter.

Eg.

```
$('div').append("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
```